# How to Use A Password Hashigh Library

Tags: dart, password-hash

Here is a suggested way of using the password hashigh library:

```
var generator = new PBKDF2();
var salt = Salt.generateAsBase64String(6); // every time is different
var hash = generator.generateKey("mytopsecretpassword", salt , 1000, 32);
```

How can I check later that the hash is true if every time salt is different and hence the hash is differnt too? And contrariwise if I set a constant salt, then it will be not safe, because we should keep that value with our code.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to store salt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt)

- generate unique salt for each password
- salt is typically stored in the database

  - even if attacker gets password and salt, they still need to crack the password, and cannot use a rainbow table.
- don't keep constant salt in the code, but you may use pepper - additional value common to all passwords and use it together with salt

> Now, since the goal of the salt is only to prevent pre-generated databases from being created, it doesn't need to be encrypted or obscured in the database. You can store it in plaintext. The goal is to force the attacker to have to crack the hashes once he gets the database, instead of being able to just look them all up in a rainbow table.
>
> However, there is one caveat. If the attacker can quietly access a salt before breaking into your database, e.g. through some script that offers the salt to anyone who asks for it, he can produce a rainbow table for that salt as easily as he could if there wasn't one. This means that he could silently take your admin account's salt and produce a nice big rainbow table, then hack into your database and immediately log in as an admin. This gives you no time to spot that a breach has occurred, and no time to take action to prevent damage, e.g. change the admin password / lock privileged accounts. This doesn't mean you should obscure your salts or attempt to encrypt them, it just means you should design your system such that the only way they can get at the salts is by breaking into the database.